# Retrieve string from json

Tags: php, json

I'm  trying to retrieve a URL string from some json code.

Here is the json code

```
    {"files":["www.example1.com"],"previews":["www.example1preview.com"],"meta":{},"userId":"guest","product":{"id":"2335","name":"standard"},"type":"u"}
```

Looking at what I've seen in the PHP manual I'm trying to retrieve previews like this.

```
    <?php
    ob_start();
    include('getjson.php');
    $meta_value_json = ob_get_clean();

    echo $meta_value_json;

    $meta_value_json = json_decode($meta_value_json);
    print $meta_value_json->{'previews'};

    ?>
```

This doesn't seem to output the value however.

Comment: For starters `$meta_value_json->previews` will be an array not a string.

Comment: `previews` is an array, even if this example only contains a single item. They don't appear to be keyed by anything, so your choices are to display the first, or loop over it and display all of them. Which do you want?

Comment: First is next best

Answer (score 1):

By experimenting with php -a command on terminal, I've put your json into json_decode and managed to get your link by just doing:

```
print $meta_value_json->previews[0];
```

The only reason to use print $meta_value_json->{'previews'}; at least according to php documentation is if you want an object as output and the key trying to retrieve is numerical or of a type that is not supported by php.

By experimenting a bit further, the reason that print $meta_value_json->{'previews'}; fails is because print expects a string, in our case here previews is an array. Therefore if you do print $meta_value_json->{'previews'}[0]; it will also work as expected.

Answer (score -2):

You need to get the value from your decoded json like this: $class->parameter.
Knowing that previews is an array, you will also need to choose a specific element from it to print ( I got the first one ):

```
   <?php
    ob_start();
    include('getjson.php');
    $meta_value_json = ob_get_clean();

    echo $meta_value_json;

    $meta_value_json = json_decode($meta_value_json);
    print $meta_value_json->previews[0]; /// get the specific value

    ?>
```

Comment: It's an object, you don't need to access it like an array.

Comment: @CD001 you can if you decode it as an array, forgot to edit that

Comment: `json_decode($meta_value_json)` on a JSON like `{ ... }` will give you a `stdClass` object - you can access any value you like from that with `$var->property` exactly the same as you can with `$var['property']` for associative arrays... your code doesn't fix anything. The specific `previews` attribute *is an array*, that's the issue.

Comment: It white screens for me.

Comment: @user3123345 check it out now